# PostgreSQL Query and/or Session CPU Usage

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way in PostgreSQL to know how much the cpu cost was per a query and/or by session. It doesn't have to be the exact system cpu usage more of a relative cost like we get with disk I/O. For Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

The [`auto_explain` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auto-explain.html) might be what you are looking for.

The [statistics collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-VIEWS) is probably the closest you can get to the Oracle v$ views.

Some more might be available in [the `pg_stat_statements` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html).

Comment: That looks interesting, but I don't see it giving any CPU usage. Really something like v$mystat which Oracle has would be ideal.

Comment: Sorry, I misread "cost" as "cost from the execution plan". See my edit for other options.

Comment: The problem with all of those is they just give a general cost or in some cases the amount of io cost performed which is nice, but it's really nice to compare two solutions and see how much the io and the cpu are different at the sql statement, session, and transaction level.

Comment: As you can reset the stats between running two statements you should at least be able to get the IO stats.